# Scoped service in controller is different from the service called in the middleware

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a custom Authentication Middelware which uses my custom service injected in the constructor.

In `MyAuthenticationHandler` I am calling a method of `MyService` which sets a property value.

```
_myService.SetCompany(company);
```

company is loaded in the authentication handler and is not null. However when I try to access the value from the controller I find that `MyService` has been reinitialized.

This is how it's set in Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyFactory>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleware is only initialized once, when you register. You need to resolve your dependency in the Invoke method.

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var service = context.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>();
        service.SetCompany("My Company");

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Now the service is properly resolved per request, rather than per application life time.

**Edit:**

i.e. in order to have your middleware be called after the authorization middelware is called you'd do something like this in your `Configure(IAppBuilder app)` method:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => { ... });
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => { ... });
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(options => { ... });
```

Then on a request, first the cookie middleware will be called. If it can handle the scheme and it fails, then following middlewares won't be executed. If it can't handle the scheme, next one will be called (jwt bearer). If that passes, the next middleware (`MyMiddleware`) will be called.

In other words, when your `MyMiddleware.Invoke()` method is being called, the user has been authenticated.

Comment: Calling GetService doesn't work context.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>(); doesn't allow type arguments. Are you sure that works on RC2? also I need to set the Company after authorization, is Invoke called after HandleAuthenticateAsync() ?

Comment: Yes, you need the `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace declaration. Or just use the non-generic version: `.GetService(typeof(IMyService))`, but then you have to cast it before you assign it to a variable

Comment: I don't think you're meant to override Invoke anymore, I get an error about having Multiple public 'Invoke' methods are available. (I'm inheriting from AuthenticationMiddleware)

Comment: The `AuthenticationMiddleware` do not provide an virtual Invoke method, so you aren't really supposed to inherit from it, at least not when you want to intercept the request in Invoke https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L65. Just make your middleware without inheriting from `AuthenticationMiddleware` and register it before or after it, depending if you want to do your stuff before or after the authentication middleware is executed. The order of registrations (the `.UseXXX` calls determines the order of exection

Comment: Thanks a lot Tseng

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for me, since I need that either of the authentication middleware should work depending on the scheme I set in the [Authorize]

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with the exact details and code you tried so far, since your statements are far off from the original question. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work if you register your middleware after the other two. Each middleware will check if it can handle scheme and process it and if successful call all following middlewares

Comment: I had a lot of issues when implementing my authentication along side Identity, I have moved this authentication to its own project and your answer works fine, but I actually implemented it on the Handler, since I also have Context there.

Comment: Tseng's code could be simplified to include the service resolution in the `Invoke()` call.

`public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IMyService service)`

**Instead of** `context.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>();`

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the service directly in the `Invoke` signature.

From the official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware#per-request-dependencies):

> If you must share a scoped service between your middleware and other types, add these services to the `Invoke` method's signature. The `Invoke` method can accept additional parameters that are populated by dependency injection.

So in your case:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IMyService service)
{
    service.SetCompany("My Company");

    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

will work.